# combining 2 activities together

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

ok so I'm making an app where I use an edit text to write anything and when I press a button it adds whatever I wrote in the edit to a listView, and it works, but I want the List to be in a different activity than the button and edit text, so I moved it without changing the code.can anyone figure this out,

BTW all the variables are public.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ArrayList<String> arrayList2;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,adapter2;
    public EditText editText,editText2;
    public ArrayList<String> itemList,itemList2;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] items = {};
        itemList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_list_layout,R.id.txtItem,itemList);
        ListView listV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
        listV.setAdapter(adapter);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.thingadd);
        Button btAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);

        String[] age = {};
        arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(age));
        itemList2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(age));
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_list__layout2,R.id.txtage,itemList2);
        ListView listV2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Age);
        listV2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.agetxt);

        btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newItem=editText.getText().toString();
                String newItem2=editText2.getText().toString();

                itemList.add(newItem);
                itemList2.add(newItem2);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite Database for that, where you would be saving data in database from one activity and reading it and displaying it in listview from another.

Comment: Yes I tried to use SQLite but the app wouldn't open if I used SQL

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to do so.

1. You can use any database service. Store the values and display them in the next activity. But this needs Internet service to be enabled in the phone.
2. You can use intent. Convert those input to string type and pass them to next activity and display them using ids. This type do not require Internet service. To know more about this, [Visit this link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/android-sending-data-from-one-activity-to-another/)